# Berryboot Raspberry pi Os & Retropie but from different drives?

Tags: retropie, berryboot, multiboot

So I'm planning my RPi 4 build and I would like to possibly have it use berryboot to choose between the Rpi OS on the sd card and retropie on an attached ssd drive (I want more room for games). Is this possible in berry boot or should I look for a different bootloader? Can berry boot boot from different drives? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried Berryboot in years, but from what I remember it was very restrictive (OS had to share kernel etc) and almost impossible to update.

If you really want to multiboot multiple OS I suggest [PINN](https://github.com/procount/pinn/blob/master/README_PINN.md).

Not sure if it would work with SSD, but see no reason why not.

PINN is supported, has an extensive set of OS available and is easily updated.